# Track Query in SQL Profiler C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, profiler

We are currently in an open beta with a app that we supply the backend API for the UI

Long story short we dont have a PROD copy of the BETA in an isolated DEV that we can work with a SQL iNjection issue that we are tyying to resolve.

Currently the backend API uses an worker process account to do all of the work NO kerberos etc as it is a commercial public APP.

What ways can we track our requests in Porfiler amongst the 200+ beta users that we have on the system @ the moment.

(NOTE: We are moving to get a Isolated PROD copy in DEV aka TEST enviroment)

Can we attach IP's to the request that we could see in backend easily ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use application name in the connection string. See: http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2006/10/24/take-advantage-of-application-name/

Note it would reduce performance by preventing pooled SQL connection reuse though.

Answer (score 1):

Inherent in the trace definition, no, you can't track the source IP address of a client connection.  If all of your database connection objects are instantiated from a common class/method, you can set the application name to be something unique to each client.  That'll let you trace it back to the source client that originated the SQL request.

Comment: Having said that you could generate a unique ID for each client and inject this into the application name holder as part of the query  ...then we could grab the IP from the UI and pass this down to the repository to then be visiable in Profiler ??

Comment: Spot on.  Of course, it's worth noting the drawback that MVC-dot-net mentioned below that you'll prevent connection pooling.  This will mostly manifest itself as a higher connection count (more memory), but with only ~200 clients this isn't a big deal on modern servers.  You'll want to remove the clientID customization before production (though it might actually be helpful to turn on for a specific client in the future to aid in in-depth debugging.)